# Knockout unable to find ViewModel properties after ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: knockout.js

So I have an ajax call and in this scenario I'm able to bind Health correctly

```
var viewModel = function () {            
    var self = this;
    self.Health = ko.observable();

    self.Load = function(data) {      
        self.Health(data.Health);      
    };

    self.LoadFromServer = function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Details", "Person", new {id = Model.ID})", null, function (jsonData) {
        self.Load(jsonData);
        });
    };
```

But to save myself from manually creating each and every property in my data, I attempted to use ko.mapping.fromJS like so

```
var viewModel = function () {            
    var self = this;

    self.Load = function(data) {      
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self)    
    };

    self.LoadFromServer = function () {
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("Details", "Person", new {id = Model.ID})", null, function (jsonData) {
        self.Load(jsonData);
        });
    };
```

Only to find javascript error 'Health is not defined' in my binding

```
<span data-bind="text: Health"></span>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Link to JSFiddle with this broken scenario
http://jsfiddle.net/rpuri/LskVR/

Thanks SO.

Comment: Where are you calling ko.applyBindings/

Comment: $(documet).ready() is where I instantiate view model and applyBindings.

Comment: After your mapping command in the `Load` function, add `console.log(self);` so you can see the actual structure of the self object. If the answer isn't apparent, please include your finding  in your post.

Comment: can you post sample of JSON data you get from server

Comment: OK, I've created a JSFiddle with this broken scenario. Console reports 'Health is not defined'. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get array from server of just one object?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dynamically add properties to my View Model in the Ajax success event using jQuery.extend

```
.done(function (raw) {
        $.extend(self, ko.mapping.fromJS(raw));
        ko.applyBindings(self);
});
```

It is also necessary to call ko.applyBindings(self) within .done() event, after the asynchronous call is complete.

The problem I'm now faced with is having to call ko.applyBindings(self) and $.extend each time I load new data.

Here is a working example. Lines 22 & 23 are performance concern.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpuri/ANgJb/

Is there a way to check before binding and extending to avoid calling each time?

Thanks SO.